# Search all element IDs on a page using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-3.5

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 page which has multiple span elements with ID containing **lblError**. How can I get all the span elements whose IDs contain **lblError**?

Comment: any reason you don't just assign them a class of "lblError" or "lbl-error" or somesuch, and query on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("span[id*='lblError']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably doing this to get around the mangled names created when using server controls you can try a couple of ways.

This will find anything that has lblError in it at the end:

```
$("[id$='lblError']");
```

Also, if you know the server control name you can do the following in your aspx page which will find your exact control:

```
$("#'<%= lblError.ClientID %>'");
```